# Customising the SplitDateTimeWidget

Tags: django

I'm editing the SplitDateTimeWidget to include the SelectTimeWidget and the SelectDateWidget. But i'm getting an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name SelectTimeWidget
```

It is importing SelectDateWidget fine and its working

```
class SplitDateTimeWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    """
    A Widget that splits datetime input into two <input type="text"> boxes.
    """
    supports_microseconds = False

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None):
        widgets = (SelectDateWidget(attrs=attrs),
                   TimeInput(attrs=attrs, format=time_format))
        super(SplitDateTimeWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            value = to_current_timezone(value)
            return [value.date(), value.time().replace(microsecond=0)]
        return [None, None]
```

As soon as i try to import and add SelectTimeWidget like so...

```
   widgets = (SelectDateWidget(attrs=attrs),
               SelectTimeWidget(attrs=attrs))
```

i get the error message? how come?

Edit - Imports

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectTimeWidget, SelectDateWidget
from django.forms.widgets import Widget, Select, MultiWidget
```

So When i import SelectDateWidget on its own and have only this within the multiwidget it works, so i though i must not be aloud to have two widgets for what ever reason but then i tried to import the SelectTimeWidget alone and use that and i still get the same error

Comment: Show us the code that actually imports these classes, and the full stack trace.

Comment: I'v added the imports, i'm not 100% sure what you mean "full stack trace" i'm kind of new to django/python

Comment: So Django does not have a `SelectTimeWidget`, which is why importing it fails. Are you using a third party app that provides this widget?